# How to add rich text editor section in debut theme shopify

Tags: shopify

I want to add rich text editor in shopify section my theme is debut and in this theme only normal rich text are work so how can i add a rich text editor.

Comment: There is only one rich text field in shopify sections. If you are looking for the full rich text editor that is present on pages/products etc... that is not possible. The normal one includes only bold, italic and link.

Comment: Thank you so much for response